# Arduino is able to connect to server but not POST temperature data to php

Tags: php, apache, post, arduino, sensors

I'm working on a project that gets arduino sensor data and sends it to my apache webserver. Right now I'm just trying to test some code as a proof of concept to see if I can send something to the server, so I ripped some code from [this guy](https://youtu.be/32VcKyI0dio) (source code in the description) with some minor modifications. The code in the arduino is as follows:

```
#include <WiFiNINA.h>

#define sensorPin A5

char ssid[] = "--WIFI--";
char pass[] = "";
boolean connected = false;
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

char server[] = "--ADDRESS--";

String postData;
String postVariable = "temp=";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to Network named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }

  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  IPAddress gateway = WiFi.gatewayIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}

void loop() {
  int reading = analogRead(sensorPin);
  float voltage = reading * 5.0;
  voltage /= 1024.0;
  float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100 ;
  float temperatureF = (temperatureC * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;

  postData = postVariable + temperatureF;

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    if (connected == false)
    {
      connected = true;
      Serial.print("Connected\n");
    }
    //Serial.print("Connected");
    client.println("POST /test/post.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: --ADDRESS--");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(postData.length());
    client.println();
    client.print(postData);
  }
  else if (connected == true)
    {
      connected = false;
      Serial.print("Not Connected\n");
    }

  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop();
  }
  Serial.println(postData);

  delay(3000);
}
```

Then I also have post.php here:

```
<?php
$time = time();
$tempF = $_POST["temp"];
$file = 'temp.html';
$data = $time."  -  ".$tempF;
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

I also created a temp.html file which is empty. The issue that I'm having is that when running the arduino code, it's able to display the temperature data and says it has connected to the server in the command prompt, but when I go back to check the server at /test/temp.html it displays nothing. Is there something that I'm missing?

I also tried another script called time.php which I was able to get to display the UTC time correctly, and I do have php installed on my Debian server. At this point, I at least know that php is working and that the arduino is connecting to the server somehow.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>

<body>

<p>Date/Time: MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm<br>
<?php echo(strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")); ?></p>

<p>Date/Time: DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm (German)<br>
<?php echo(strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")); ?></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably won't solve the problem, but notice you're overwriting the whole file everytime PHP gets the data; you might want to add FILE_APPEND in your `file_put_contents` call.    PS: I'd suggest always using relative paths (`'./temp.html'`)

Comment: I just tried to run the post.php script again, only with the time function, and it seems not to be working. Perhaps there's some kind of library or extention that I'm missing? How do I get access to this?

Comment: You should need no library for this, as far as I know.   Are you running php from the terminal? If so, you should be able to see when the Arduino connects to the server; it usually writes a line with the client's IP, the path to the requested resource, the code (200 for success) and the method used

Comment: Yes, I'm using php from the terminal, how do I check that? Do I just look at the apache logs from the terminal using "sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache/access.log"?